# Out Parameter in MySql

Tags: mysql, .net, sql

I have written code to insert in two different table but i am getting error...

```
DELIMITER  //
create procedure usp_ItemView(
    p_itemname varchar(50),
    p_company varchar(50),
    p_model varchar(50),
    p_unit varchar(50),
    p_photo varchar(50),
    p_color varchar(50),
    p_size varchar(50),
    p_weight varchar(50),
    p_stock varchar(50),
    out p_maxsi int    
)
begin
    insert into item_tbl(
        item_name,company,model_no,unit,photo,
        color,size,weight,stock 
    )
    values(
        p_itemname,p_company,p_model,p_unit,p_photo,
        p_color,p_size,p_weight,p_stock
    );
    set p_maxsi = select max(sl_no) from item_tbl;
    insert into stock(itemslno,quantity)
    values(
        p_maxsi,p_stock
    );
end //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Can you mention what error you are getting?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select max(sl_no) from item_tbl; insert into stock(itemslno,qua' at line 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a syntax error in the line

```
set p_maxsi = select max(sl_no) from item_tbl;
```

Try using this:

```
  set p_maxsi = (select max(sl_no) from item_tbl);
```

Hope this helps. Let me know. Best Luck.. :)